# Parse string using delimiter and pick up elements from 2nd index till the last in Shell / Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have a string of following format:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g
```

I want to parse this string on delimiter '|' into array, then I want to iterate over the array from 2nd index, i.e. (c d e f g) and then I want to validate each of these array values individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with pure Bash:

```
teststring='a|b|c|d|e|f|g'

IFS='|' read -d '' -a arr <<<"$teststring"

for (( idx=2 ; idx < ${#arr[*]} ; idx++ )) ; do
    echo "validate ${arr[idx]}"
done
```

Comment: The original answer did not work when fields had newline characters in them (e.g. `teststring=$'a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h\ni'`).  I've fixed the problem by editing it to add the option `-d ''` to `read`.  It still can't handle fields with NUL (ASCII 0) characters in them, and would need considerable modification to be able to do that.

Comment: Just from a stylistic standpoint, your validate could be `echo "array[$idx] ${arr[$idx]}"`. Nothing wrong your way, it was just always more helpful to me to see `array[1] X`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Try awk:

```
echo "a|b|c|d|e|f|g" | awk -F'|' '{ if ($2 == "b") {print "Yo i found b" } else printf("i dont know <%s>", $2)}'
```

awk -F - With field seperator as "|"
if - $2 is second field am comparing with b, saying if i find b then print i found it else say i dont know b

Answer (score 1):

To parse the string to array

**Using sed**

```
$ array= ( $(echo "a|b|c|d|e|f|g" | sed 's/|/ /g') )
```

**Using tr**

```
$ array=( $(echo "a|b|c|d|e|f|g" | tr '|' ' ') )
```

Any loop can help you iterate through the array

for example `while` loop will do

```
i=2
while [ $i -lt  ${#array[@]} ]
do 
echo ${array[$i]}
(( i=$i+1 ))
done
```

Will give an output as

```
c
d
e
f
g
```

Comment: These attempted solutions don't work if the fields have whitespace characters in them.  They might also fail if any of the fields have globbing metacharacters in them (e.g. `...|h*i`); it depends on what files are in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "a|b|c|d|e|f|g" | awk -F\| '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {print $i}}'
```

Using "|" as delimiter, print from 2nd field to the last field.

Comment: There are a few problems with this attempt at a solution.  First, the array, `arr`, is redundant.  The `print` does not use an array element, it uses the i-th field.  Second, the field indexing is off by one.  Since fields are numbered from 1, the first one to process is field number 3.  The awk code can be reduced to `awk -F\| '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) {print $i}}'`.  Finally, it doesn't work if fields have newline characters in them (e.g. `echo $'a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h\ni' | ...`).